# Simple Multiple Step

Tags: jquery, css

[image]

[JSfiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gohuomcc/)

HTML

```
<div id="status-buttons" class="text-center">
  <a href="/1"><span>1</span></a>
  <a href="/2"><span>2</span></a>
  <a href="/3"><span>3</span></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#status-buttons a {
    display:inline-block;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-right: 20px; }
  #status-buttons a span {
    color: white;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding-top: 5px; 
}

#status-buttons a.active span {
  background: #00BC8C; }

.circle, #status-buttons a {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #5dc5c5;
  margin-right: 10px; 
  text-align:center;

}
```

Attempted the circles. As in the image, I am stuck with lines between the circles. Tried add border-bottom, it does not appear. Not think that width in div can be useful for lines? Is there any way around that so when click different link on circle, number of circles and its lines will have active classes?

Another question: Supposedly, the links take us to the different page with different form, is it possible to make circle active? Only the way I could think is to make circle active in each page, so if any link page is clicked, for example, click #2, it will show 1 and 2 circles active. It might be a cheat. Is there another better way around it?

Help appreciated.

Comment: How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/zyvke8sy/ its a bit limited in the fact that the pseudo elemement has a fixed width...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar recently.

```css
.progressbar {
        margin-top: 40px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        overflow: hidden;
        counter-reset: step; 
    }
    .progressbar li {
        list-style-type: none;
        color: #555555;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 9px;
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
        position: relative; 
    }
    .progressbar li:before {
        content: counter(step);
        counter-increment: step;
        width: 20px;
        line-height: 20px;
        display: block;
        font-size: 10px;
        color: #333;
        background: #bfbfbf;
        border-radius: 20px;
        margin: 0 auto 5px auto; 
    }
    .progressbar li:after {
        content: '';
        width: 100%;
        height: 2px;
        background: #bfbfbf;
        position: absolute;
        left: -50%;
        top: 9px;
        margin-left: 5px;
        z-index: -1; 
    }
    .progressbar li:first-child:after {
        content: none; 
    }
    .progressbar li.stepped {
        color: #900028;
        font-weight: bold; 
    }
    .progressbar li.stepped:before, 
    .progressbar li.stepped:after{
        background: #900028;
        color: white; 
    }
```

```html
<ul class="progressbar">
      <li class="stepped">Step 1</li>
      <li class="stepped">Step 2</li>
      <li class="stepped">Step 3</li>
      <li>Step 4</li>
      <li>Step 5</li>
    </ul>
```

(credit: http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/jquery-multi-step-form-with-progress-bar)

Comment: I saw the similar one, but I tried to modify to circle and it doesn't look good. hmm. will have to try again

Comment: to make them circles, just make the border radius, width and height all the same size. updated my answer to make them circles

Comment: i realized that you are using text inside li while mine is links. so i see 2 numbers of each: 1 1, 2 2, 3 3, 4 4  - update fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gohuomcc/1/

Comment: my apologies for trouble but how to move the line down because i make circle bigger. the line is out of place

Comment: So the numbers are generated by the css step property. If you need the numbers inside to be linked, you should change `li:before` to `li a` and remove `content: counter(step); counter-increment: step;` you can also remove `counter-reset: step;`. as for adjusting the line, that is controlled by the `top` property in `li:after`. updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gohuomcc/5/